# Invisible Fullscreen View with Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview

I'm trying to create an application which change the mouse cursor, but to do that the cursor must be inside a NSView. To do this all the time, I would need to have an intangible and invisible fullscreen view.

I've created a subclass of NSView which implement the following code to became full screen in initWithFrame:

```
[self enterFullScreenMode:[NSScreen mainScreen] withOptions:nil];
```

And using that code, I can change the cursor inside the view:

```
- (void)resetCursorRects{
    [self addCursorRect:[self bounds] cursor:appCursor];
}
```

The cursor changed successfully, but here comes the first problem: the view is in fullscreen, but it's visible, like a gray background. I've tried this method:

```
[[self window] setOpaque:NO];
```

And this one:

```
[[self window] setBackgroundColor:[NSColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.0]];
```

But both of them just change the view color to black instead of gray. How can I fix that?

Comment: I'm not sure that `setBackgroundColor` with 0 alpha is the same as `setAlphaValue` for the window.   See [Apple Sample Code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/FunkyOverlayWindow/Listings/FunkyOverlayWindow_OverlayWindow_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10000391-FunkyOverlayWindow_OverlayWindow_m-DontLinkElementID_8).  You may have stared at that already, but that *is* a difference.

Comment: I've already tried that too. Same result, black fullscreen view. But it was a nice try :)

Comment: Hey did u solve that?  I too cant seem to get the Fullscreen working on NSView 'enterFullScreenMode'.   I get a gray screen.

Comment: I had no success. Sorry.